# Export chart without hidden series labels in legend

Tags: highcharts

When exporting my chart after hiding some series, it still shows their labels in the legend (as hidden). Is there a way to display only the labels of the active series in the legend ?

[image: Demo chart from Highcharts. "Installation" and "Sales & Distribution" series are hidden but their labels appear in the legend.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is not supported in Highharts by default, but you can easily wrap `init` method and for export set the `showInLegend` option based on the series visibility:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'init', function(proceed, options, callback) {
    if (options.chart && options.chart.forExport && options.series) {
        $.each(options.series, function() {
            if (this.visible === false) {
                this.showInLegend = false;
            }
        });
    }

    return proceed.call(this, options, callback);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x2gy7f0q/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts